# Нужен ли пробел между словом и многочием? И др

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

> Где мне теперь самоутверждаться-то? Все меня **унижают...** я же всего лишь фельдшер по **образованию...** Пришлось на форуме русского языка! Там хотя бы можно людей с высшим образованием поунижать всласть! Там же есть **эти...** кандидаты и доктора наук даже, профессура! Вот этих носом в дерьмо окунуть - самый кайф! Оргазм! Если честно, у меня здесь есть и другие ники. Это когда нужно массовку создать, затравить кого-нибудь. Самый мёд - академика какого-нибудь "опустить"! Бывало и такое! Пинком прям с форума вылетали.  **Да...** не выдерживали моего авторитета! А мне хоть компенсация за низкий статус в реальной жизни!!! Знала бы ты, как они меня все там  **уважают...** просто преклоняются! А **ты...** за 5 **лет...** так ни разу даже и не позвонила! Не спросила, как я себя
> чувствую! Ты ведь знала, что я в больнице лежу? Знала! Почему не навестила? Смс-ку не сбросила даже!!! С днем рождения не поздравила!!! Как так можно? Чего ты молчишь? Деревяшка ты бездушная, Катя!!! Помру ведь я **скоро...** онкология, заинька! Давай успеем хоть попрощаться **по-человечески...** А? Чего я тебе там изменил-то? **Подумаешь...** на пять минут штаны у соседки **снял...** Это и не я вовсе! Это она сама набросилась на меня! Я её даже отталкивал резко! А она прилипла - и ни в **какую...** что ты будешь **делать...** Ты сама виновата, что так быстро из булочной вернулась!!!

1. Надо ли делать пробел между последней буквой слова и многочием?
2. После многоточия можно писать слова с маленькой буквы? Или можно как угодно?

Comment: Здравствуйте, Варелик-Олимпиец! Предлагаю **глобально** уменьшить количество ненужных слов.

Comment: Римма Михайлова, сделайте, пожалуйста, исключение! Это послание... зашифрованное! Тем более я успел исправить "ВНА" на "ВА"! УФФ... Вспомнил тот ролик на Ютубе :))

Comment: Если это зашифрованное послание, то при чем тут русский язык?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Многоточие не отбивается пробелом от предыдущего слова.

**2.** Многоточие может заканчивать предложение (и тогда следующее после него слово пишется с прописной буквы), а может не заканчивать (и тогда следующее слово пишется со строчной; разумеется, если это не имя и т. п.).
Пример из справочника Розенталя (§ 12, [примечание 1](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/24.htm#%D0%B7_02)):

> *Жена его... впрочем, они были совершенно довольны друг другом* (Гоголь)
> (многоточие поглощает запятую перед вводным словом *впрочем*).

Comment: Ясно, спасибо!!!

Comment: @Nektoid Три пары скобок подряд — не многовато ли? От второй пары можно безболезненно избавиться. И читать-воспринимать ответ будет удобнее.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова нельзя избавиться, потому что у Розенталя так. Это же цитата.

Comment: Вы же ссылок по какой-то причине не даете, приходится рыться. Пожалуй, я "подокрасивлю" Ваш ответ. Надеюсь, Вы не против.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова я же указал: "Розенталь "Справочник по правописанию...", § 12, примеч.". Чем не ссылка? Тем, что не нажимается? Эх, привыкли вы, молодые, к интернетам вашим...

Comment: Ои-ё! *...привыкли вы, молодые...* Порадовали Вы меня, окрылили прям — невообразимо!

Answer (score 0):

Если писать ручкой на листке бумаги, то проблемы с пробелами перед многоточием не возникает. Только в печатном тексте вопрос наличия или отсутствия пробела перед многоточием имеет место быть.

Comment: behemothus, я, например, всегда печатала с пробелом перед многоточием. Теперь же я точно запомню, как надо. Благодаря этому замечательному тексту.  Я плакала и смеялась. Русскому языку ничего не сделается, не переживайте. Он на то и есть, чтобы люди коммуницировали. А здесь ещё и образовательная функция текста (я лично крепко запомнила, как надо, из-за обилия примеров).